# Netbeans 8.1 randomly crashes on Ubuntu 17.04 GNOME (Wayland)

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, netbeans

I have OpenJDK 8 and Netbeans 8.1 installed on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04,
 Wayland. (everything installed from apt, No PPA).

> The crash is not observable on GNOME Legacy session. Only on Wayland.
>   More descriptive version info is below:

**Java**:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.17.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)`

**Netbeans**: `Version: 8.1+dfsg3-1`

Netbeans seems to work fine for some time after start, till it crashes abruptly. Until the crash, one could edit and run java code.